# Inserting RTF content in to Quill displays plain text

Tags: javascript, rtf, quill

I am simply attempting to insert rich text format content in to the editor via the API call **insertText()**, however, this is inserted as plain text. Is this intended? Is there no way to insert rtf content in to the editor via the API? If this is not possible, please suggest a better alternative.

I've tried other API calls such as setContent etc. We are currently using the DevExpress rich text editor, however it is very slow and an utter pain with our current implementation as it was made for MVC based projects, but we use a single page app built on Ember.

```
var quill = new Quill('#rtf-editor', {
            modules: {
                toolbar: false
            },
            theme: 'snow'
        });

        var bindingContext = this.get('bindingContext');

        quill.disable();
        quill.insertText(0, bindingContext.get('content.termsOfUseText'));
```

I would expect rich text format content to appear with all formatting, however it just appears as plaintext

Example of actual outcome:

```
{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\defchp \fs18}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs18 Normal;}{\*\cs1\fs18 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs18 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs18\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs18\ql\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfb3\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tscellpaddft3\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}
```

This is the sort of thing that appears in the editor, in case I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the API documentation, it appears that Quill's `insertText` is not the appropriate way to do this (the `text` parameter appears to accept plain text and the next parameter `format` appears to accept the formatting that needs to be applied to that plain text).

It it not clear what kind of representation the rich text you have has, but in terms of Quill, it understands rich text in terms of Deltas and one possible way that I see to do what you intend to do is to somehow have your rich text converted to HTML and then use the quills `dangerouslyPasteHTML` method to insert that HTML into the editor.

Refer the documentation for more info: https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It is not clear what kind of representation the rich text you have has"?

Comment: `{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\defchp \fs18}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs18 Normal;}{\*\cs1\fs18 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs18 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs18\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs18\ql\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfb3\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tscellpaddft3\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}`

This looks like some representation of rich text since it has properties like `fonttbl`, `colortbl`. I do not know how to interpret this and as far as I know, quill is not able to interpret this either.

Comment: Well it is just called "rich text format" or "RTF", that's the name for the representation. I would have assumed rich text editors would able to interpret it, due to the name, but clearly I'm mistaken.